# Java regex to put a string that doesn't start with # inside <p> </p> tag

Tags: java, regex, string

**Input:** `#This is a header\nSome line\nAnother line`

**Desired output:**

```
#This is a header

<p>Some Line</p>

<p>Another line</p>
```

I've tried this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(^|\\n)*(?!#)([^\\n]+)(\\n|$)", "$1<p>$2</p>$3");
```

But it won't work correctly.
So i'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("(?m)^(#.*\r?\n)(.*)(\r?\n)(.*)", "$1<p>$2</p>$3<p>$4</p>")`

Comment: thanks, it works! please, could you explain this to me?

Comment: It matches any line starting with `#`, and then captures the 2 lines below that one into separate groups. Then, tags are added in the replacement pattern. I just do not understand if the string you showed is a part of a longer text or is it in some fixed format?

Comment: there's a possibility of the string being a part of a longer text

Comment: Ok, so my comment above should be the answer I think. Please let me know if the answer below is working for you,  and if not, I will post mine.

Comment: Then please accept the answer below, it is almost identical to my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.replaceAll("(?m)^(#[^\r\n]+)\r?\n([^\r\n]+)\r?\n([^\r\n]+)$", "<p>$1</p><p>$2</p><p>$3</p>")
```

Regex: `(?m)^(#[^\r\n]+)\r?\n([^\r\n]+)\r?\n([^\r\n]+)$`

- `(?m)` adds the multine flag. This means The `^` and `$` characters behave differently.
- `^` start of any line
- `(#[^\n\r]+)` Group 1: literal `#` 1 or more non-newline and non-carriage-return characters
- `\r?\n` optional carriage-return character, newline and non-carriage-return character
- `([^\n]+)` Group 2: 1 or more non-newline and non-carriage-return characters
- `\r?\n` optional carriage-return character, newline and non-carriage-return character
- `([^\n]+)` Group 3: 1 or more non-newline and non-carriage-return characters
- `$` end of any line

Replacer: `<p>$1</p><p>$2</p><p>$3</p>`

`$n` will insert that group number. So `$1` will become "#This is a header".

Comment: FYI, In case line breaks are in CRLF format, this might not be the best solution.

Comment: I did consider this, but the original post seemed to discount that. I've now tweaked to handle `\r` also.

Comment: Yes, but now, it matches the `#` anywhere in the string, even in the middle of a line.

Comment: I also understand that, and have tweaked for it. The reason I don't worry about such things for the first version is that I base it all on what the OP has shown us in the first place. He showed that he wasn't worried about \r, and he showed there would be no other content within the string. If the OP tries the code and says there's an issue, or there's an actual bug with my code, I can work on it to fix it. Otherwise I'm just putting a whole lot of effort in for possibly no reason. Thanks for the feedback, but in this case I'll wait for Egor to comment with further requirements.

Comment: So another content is also possible.
There could be lines starting with # anywhere in the string.
And the number of lines in the string is unlimited.
How do I take that into account?

Comment: So do you want to capture every instance of "header, 2 lines of text"?

Comment: I've added the "multiline" flag, which should allow it to match at any point in the string (see the edited answer).